# Remove trailing string

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, command

In a bash script I have the following command which removes the trailing `\r\n` from the last line of a file.

```
# Copy the new last line but remove trailing \r\n
tail -1 $TMPOUT | perl -p -i -e 's/\r\n$//' >>$TMPOUT.1
```

It's currently using Perl to trim the `\r\n` off, but the target system I'll need to run this on won't have Perl or any other scripts (uClinux/Busybox embedded device).

How can I achieve the same in 'pure' bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tr` command then,

```
tail -1 $TMPOUT|tr -d '\r\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

This `sed` should work:

```
sed -i.bak -n $'$s/\r$//p' "$TMPOUT"
```